# Imprimir sequencia de números repetindo em progressão aritmética

Tags: c

Faça um programa para imprimir:

```
1
2   2
3   3   3
.....
n   n   n   n   n   n  ... n
```

para um n informado pelo usuário. Use uma função que receba um valor n inteiro e imprima até a n-ésima linha.

Por que não funciona?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void tarefa(int r){
    int e;

    for (e=0; e<=r;e++){

printf(" %d  ", e);


    }


}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int x, j;


    scanf("%d", &x);

    for(j=0; j<=x; j++){

    tarefa(j);  

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dá erro? Qual? Ou se não dá erro, qual é a saída do programa? Já tentou fazer o teste de mesa?

Comment: Qual o erro? Não está imprimindo o que deveria ou está soltando alguma falha durante a execução?

Comment: Seria a falta de um fim de linha? Note também que você não precisa (nem deve) passar o argumento 0

Comment: o problema era no compilador...

Comment: ja esta funcionando

Comment: Então poste o que você fez para resolver a questão como uma resposta, e ajude as próximas pessoas que se depararem com esse mesmo problema

Comment: O problema não era no compilador, o problema nunca é no compilador. E pode fazer o que for que não vai resolver, o algoritmo estava errado.

Comment: bigown já resolveu... tambem fiz no ideone: https://ideone.com/vOCB9O

Comment: obrigado ai...nn tava dando certo msm

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, em questões de programação competitiva, normalmente eles especificam para a quebra de linha ser apenas o `\n`. Nesses casos, talvez o seu código pudesse gerar um `Presentation Error` no BOCA ou no URI Judge.

Comment: @PedroJoao A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Comment: @PedroJoao? A resposta do Maniero respondeu sua dúvida?

Answer (score 7):

Tem dois problemas., O laço deve começar do 1, afinal se cada número deve ser repetido o número de vezes dele mesmo, não tem porque imprimir o 0, e também estava imprimindo o contador e não o número que deve ser repetido, então troquei o `e` pelo `r`. Poderia ter começado pelo 1 no outro laço.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tarefa(int r) {
    for (int e = 1; e <= r; e++) printf(" %d  ", r);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    for (int j = 1; j <= x; j++) tarefa(j);  
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mKIw2u). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vrvqisic-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SequenceRepetition.c).

Comment: Posso sugerir um `printf("\n");` no final da função `tarefa`? Se for um problema de programação competitiva, a falta da quebra de linha geraria um `Presentation Error`. Fiz [este fork](https://ideone.com/BxEqXk) com essa mudança, e também começando o laço da `main` com `j = 1`

Comment: É possível sim, depois eu mexo.